# Optimized low-accuracy approximation to `rootn(x, n)`

Tags: algorithm, math, floating-point, bit-manipulation

`rootn (float_t x, int_t n)` is a function that computes the *n*-th root x<sup>1/n</sup> and is supported by some programming languages such as  [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/rootn.html). When IEEE-754 floating-point numbers are used, efficient low-accuracy starting approximations for any `n` can be generated based on simple manipulation of the underlying bit pattern, assuming only normalized operands `x` need to be processed.

The binary exponent of `root (x, n)` will be 1/n of the binary exponent of `x`. The exponent field of an IEEE-754 floating-point number is biased. Instead of un-biasing the exponent, dividing it, and re-biasing the result, we can simply divide the biased exponent by `n`, then apply an offset to compensate for the previously neglected bias. Furthermore, instead of extracting, then dividing, the exponent field, we can simply divide the  entire operand `x`, re-interpreted as an integer. The required offset is trivial to find as an argument of 1 will return a result of 1 for any `n`.

If we have two helper functions at our disposal, `__int_as_float()` which reinterpretes an IEEE-754 `binary32` as `int32`, and `__float_as_int()` which reinterpretes an `int32` operand as `binary32`, we arrive at the following low-accuracy approximation to `rootn (x, n)` in straightforward fashion:

```
rootn (x, n) ~= __int_as_float((int)(__float_as_int(1.0f)*(1.0-1.0/n)) + __float_as_int(x)/n)
```

The integer division `__float_as_int (x) / n` can be reduced to a shift or multiplication plus shift by [well-known optimizations of integer division by constant divisor](https://gmplib.org/~tege/divcnst-pldi94.pdf). Some worked examples are:

```
rootn (x,  2) ~= __int_as_float (0x1fc00000 + __float_as_int (x) / 2)  // sqrt (x)
rootn (x,  3) ~= __int_as_float (0x2a555556 + __float_as_int (x) / 3)  // cbrt (x)
rootn (x, -1) ~= __int_as_float (0x7f000000 - __float_as_int (x) / 1)  // rcp (x)
rootn (x, -2) ~= __int_as_float (0x5f400000 - __float_as_int (x) / 2)  // rsqrt (x)
rootn (x, -3) ~= __int_as_float (0x54aaaaaa - __float_as_int (x) / 3)  // rcbrt (x)
```

With all these approximations, the result will be exact only when `x` = 2<sup>n*m</sup> for integer `m`. Otherwise, the approximation will provide an overestimation compared to the true mathematical result. We can approximately halve the *maximum relative error* by reducing the offset slightly, leading to a balanced mix of underestimation and overestimation. This is easily accomplished by a binary search for the optimal offset that uses all floating-point numbers in the interval [1, 2<sup>n</sup>) as test cases. Doing so, we find:

```
rootn (x, 2) ~= __int_as_float (0x1fbb4f2e + __float_as_int(x)/2) // max rel err = 3.47474e-2
rootn (x, 3) ~= __int_as_float (0x2a51067f + __float_as_int(x)/3) // max rel err = 3.15547e-2
rootn (x,-1) ~= __int_as_float (0x7ef311c2 - __float_as_int(x)/1) // max rel err = 5.05103e-2
rootn (x,-2) ~= __int_as_float (0x5f37642f - __float_as_int(x)/2) // max rel err = 3.42128e-2
rootn (x,-3) ~= __int_as_float (0x54a232a3 - __float_as_int(x)/3) // max rel err = 3.42405e-2
```

Some may notice that the computation for `rootn (x,-2)` is basically the initial portion of [Quake's fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root).

Based on observing the differences between the original raw offset, and the final offset *optimized to minimize the maximum relative error*, I could formulate a heuristic for the secondary correction and thus the final, optimized, offset value.

However, I am wondering whether it is possible to determine the optimal offset by some closed-form formula, such that the maximum absolute value of the relative error, max (|(approx(x,n) - x<sup>1/n</sup>) / x<sup>1/n</sup>|), is minimized for all `x` in [1,2<sup>n</sup>). For ease of exposition, we can restrict to `binary32` (IEEE-754 single-precision) numbers.

I am aware that in general, there is no closed-form solution for minimax approximations, however I am under the impression that closed-form solutions do exist for the case of polynomial approximations to algebraic functions like *n*-th root. In this case we have (piecewise) linear approximation.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what your objective function is.  You want to minimise average relative error?  Worst-cast relative error?  Root-mean-square relative error?  Number of cases where relative error is above some threshold?

Comment: The objective is to minimize the maximum relative error. I will clarify the question.

Comment: I realize I'm side-stepping the question, but you might be happiest with just doing one or two Newton-Raphson steps following the initial approximation. For well-conditioned systems like this, each one essentially doubles the precision.

Comment: I am fully aware of common approaches to refining starting approximations for n-th root. Side remark: I frequently use iterations with cubic convergence rather than Newton-Raphson which provides only quadratic convergence. I am also aware that the offset needed for a optimal starting approximation using the approach above will change *slightly* based on the exact nature of the subsequent iteration. However for now I am wondering whether there is a close-formed expression just for an optimal approximation itself, which seems to be a hard enough problem.

Comment: The input where the approximation for the optimal offsets is relatively largest seems to always be slightly less than a power of 2. This suggests to me a plan of attack where we ballpark the offset by considering only the bias adjustment, figure out which power of 2 should be near worst (I would conjecture that this can be computed simply from the approximate offset), then solve some equation where we know what the relevant pieces of the piecewise functions involved should be.

Comment: Our observations are not in agreement. For some `n` I see the effect you state, but according to my search application: `pow=-2  offset=5f37642f  maxerr=3.42128873e-2 @ 2.57685351e+0` and `pow=-3  offset=54a232a3  maxerr=3.42405885e-2 @ 7.20604515e+0`. Reference function and error computation are performed in double precision. I will double check that code now.

Comment: I found a small issue in my generating app. After fixing it, I see this: `pow=+2 offset=1fbb4f2e  maxerr = 3.47474464e-2 @ 2.00000000e+0; pow=+3 offset=2a51067f  maxerr = 3.15546888e-2 @ 1.10096800e+0; pow=-1 offset=7ef311c2  maxerr = 5.05102873e-2 @ 1.00000000e+0; pow=-2 offset=5f37642f  maxerr = 3.42128376e-2 @ 2.57699323e+0; pow=-3 offset=54a232a3  maxerr = 3.42405452e-2 @ 7.20604372e+0` Note that for `rootn(x,3)` the maximum error is *not* for an argument slightly less than a power of two.

Comment: `maxerr` reported is the absolute value of the maximum relative error found. Looking over the intermediate outputs I see that the actual value is either negative or positive, depending on what `n` I look at. For each `n`, with the optimal offset found, the maximum overestimation and maximum underestimation are *very* close, as we would expect from a properly balanced approximation.

Comment: So when n > 0, is the argmax of the ratio (actual result / expect result) a power of two always?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "argmax of the ratio [...]". If you are referring to the absolute value of the maximum relative error the answer is "no", see the data for n=3 above, where the maximum relative error occurs at `1.10096800e+0` which is not near a power of two. It seems that the relative error at some powers of two is often close to the maximum relative error, but I haven't examined this in detail.

Comment: I'm confused, because my code doesn't agree. I'm not talking about `maxerr` -- no absolute value.

Comment: I mean the literal maximum value of `rootn(x, n) / x**(1/n)` for `x in [1, 2^n)` (this is one side of the two-sided relative error that you're optimizing, no?).

Comment: This is the raw max. rel. error data before taking the absolute value. The maximum relative error can occur both with overestimation and underestimation: `pow=+2 offset=1fbb4f2e  max. rel. err =  3.47474464e-2 @ 2.00000000e+0; pow=+3 offset=2a51067f  max. rel. err = -3.15546888e-2 @ 1.10096800e+0; pow=-1 offset=7ef311c2  max. rel. err = -5.05102873e-2 @ 1.00000000e+0; pow=-2 offset=5f37642f  max. rel. err =  3.42128376e-2 @ 2.57699323e+0; pow=-3 offset=54a232a3  max. rel. err = -3.42405452e-2 @ 7.20604372e+0;` If you compute `rootn(x, n) / x**(1/n)` that is absolute, not relative error.

Comment: I have modified the last paragraph of the question to include a formula showing what error I wish to minimize, instead of relying on a textual description alone.

Answer (score 8):

Here's some Octave (MATLAB) code that computes offsets for positive n assuming the conjectures below. Seems to work for 2 and 3, but I suspect that one of the assumptions breaks down when n is too large. No time to investigate right now.

```
% finds the best offset for positive n
% assuming that the conjectures below are true
function oint = offset(n)
% find the worst upward error with no offset
efrac = (1 / log(2) - 1) * n;
evec = [floor(efrac) ceil(efrac)];
rootnvec = 2 .^ (evec / n);
[abserr i] = max((1 + evec / n) ./ rootnvec);
relerr = abserr - 1;
rootnx = rootnvec(i);
% conjecture: z such that approx(z, n) = 1
% should have the worst downward error
fun = @(o) relerr - o / rootnx + (1 / (1 + o * n) ^ (1 / n) - 1);
oreal = fzero(fun, [0 1]);
oint = round((127 * (1 - 1 / n) - oreal) * 2 ^ 23);
```

---

Partial answer for positive n only -- I'm just going to nibble a bit by conjecturing the worst overestimate, assuming that we don't adjust the offset downward.

Let's define an idealized version of the approximation for `x in [1, 2^n)`.

```
rootn-A(x, n) = 1 + floor(lg(x))/n + ((x/2^floor(lg(x))) - 1) / n
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                    contribution of       contribution of the
                     the exponent             significand
```

We want to maximize `rootn-A(x, n) / x^(1/n)`.

It seems experimentally that the maximum occurs when `x` is a power of two. In this case, the significand term is zero and `floor(lg(x)) = lg(x)`, so we can maximize

```
(1 + lg(x)/n) / x^(1/n).
```

Substitute `y = lg(x)/n`, and we can maximize `(1 + y) / 2^y` for `y in [0, 1)` such that `n*y` is an integer. Dropping the integrality condition, it is a calculus exercise to show that the max of this concave function is at `y = 1/log(2) - 1`, about `0.4426950408889634`. It follows that the maximum for `x` a power of two is at either `x = 2^floor((1/log(2) - 1) * n)` or `x = 2^ceil((1/log(2) - 1) * n)`. I conjecture that one of these is in fact the global maximum.

On the underestimation end, it appears that we want `x` such that the output of `rootn(x, n)` is `1`, at least for small `n`. More to come later hopefully.

Comment: I found a 2012 [thesis](https://tbach.web.cern.ch/tbach/thesis/literature/fastinvsquare_robertson.pdf) that analyzes the mathematics of Quake's inverse square root and appears to include a discussion on finding offset that will minimize maximum relative error. I am too tired to read through the lengthy exposition, but figure this might hold the key for finding a generalized error minimization approach for n-th root approximation.

Comment: @njuffa Would you be interested in a program that finds the approximate optimum (up to the foibles of floating point vs real numbers) in O(n) floating-point operations (but not a closed form)?

Comment: This question seems to have attracted a fair amount of interest, so I think for the benefit of the general public any solution that finds offset(n) in a significantly more efficient way than brute-force search and delivers better results than a simple heuristic (correction to the offset provided by the basic formula of `-0x44000` for positive `n` and `-0x88000` for negative `n`) would be useful. I'd be happy to upvote and release the bounty, but would want a closed-form solution for acceptance. I haven't made much progress in my own efforts to find one.

Comment: @njuffa Posted some Octave code that summarizes the results of my conjectures. Not sure when I'll have more time to work on this.