# Does optimization of the initial guess make the Babylonian method of finding square roots fast?

Tags: java, algorithm, square-root

The Babylonian aka Heron's method seems to be one of the faster algorithms for finding the square root for a number n. How fast it converges is dependent on how far of your initial guess is.

Now as number n increases its root x as its percentage decreases. 
root(10):10 - 31%
10:100 - 10%
root(100) : 100 - 3%
root(1000) : 1000 - 1%
So basically for each digit in the number divide by around 3. Then use that as your intial guess. Such as -

```
 public static double root(double n ) {
      //If number is 0 or negative return the number
            if(n<=0)
                return n ;
     //call to a method to find number of digits
            int num = numDigits(n)  ;
            double guess =  n ;
    //Divide by 0.3 for every digit from second digit onwards
            for (int i = 0 ; i < num-1 ; ++i )
                guess = guess * 0.3;
    //Repeat until it converges to within margin of error
            while (!(n-(guess*guess) <= 0.000001 && n-(guess*guess) >= 0 )) {
                double divide = n/guess ;
                guess = Math.abs(0.5*(divide+guess)) ;

            }

            return Math.abs(guess)  ;
        }
```

Does this help and optimize the algorithm. And is this O(n)  ?

Comment: a function to find the number of digits is the decimal logarithm function; actually, its 1+ the integer part of the decimal logarithm of that number

Comment: also, instead of iterating like this: `for (int i = 0 ; i < num-1 ; ++i )  guess = guess * 0.3;` , which adds complexity, you could do `guess=guess* Math.pow(0.3, num-1)`

Comment: That's a pretty bad convergence condition, it does not take the magnitude of the number into account at all so it only works well over a specific range of inputs.

Comment: @Newtonfan01  - I'm aware it's log10 and initially used the Math.log10() method. However I switched it over to a simple method that uses modulo to calculate the number of digits because I think finding the exact log will take more time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. What works even better is to exploit the floating point representation, by dividing the binary exponent approximately by two, because operating on the floating-point bits is very fast. See [Optimized low-accuracy approximation to `rootn(x, n)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32042673/2144669).

Answer (score 0):

My belief is that the complexity of an algorithm is independent on the input provided. (the complexity is a general characteristic of that algorithm, we cannot say that algorithm x has complexity O1 for input I1 and complexity O2 for input I2). Thus, no matter what initial value you provide, it should not improve complexity. It may improve the number of iterations for that particular case, but that's a different thing. Reducing the number of iterations by half still means the same complexity. Keep in mind that n, 2*n, n/3 all fit into the O(n) class .

Now, with regard to the actual complexity, i read on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) that

```
This is a quadratically convergent algorithm, which means that the number of correct digits of the approximation roughly doubles with each iteration.
```

This means you need as many iterations as the number of precision decimals that you expect. Which is constant. If you need 10 exact decimals, 10 is a constant, being totally independent of n.

But on wikipedia's example, they chose from the very begining a candidate which had the same order of magnitude as the correct answer (600 compared to 354).  However, if your initial guess is way too wrong (by orders of magnitude) you will need some extra iterations to cut down/add to the necessary digits. Which will add complexity. Suppose correct answer is 10000 , while your initial guess is 10. The difference is 4 orders of magnitude, and i think in this case, the complexity needed to reach the correct magnitude is proportional to the difference between the number of digits of your guess and the number of digits of the correct answer. Since number of digits is approximativelly log(n), in this case the extra complexity is `log(corect_answer) -log(initial_guess)`, taken as absolute value.

To avoid this, pick a number that has the right number of digits, which is generally half the number of digits of your initial number. My best choice would be picking the first half of the number as a candidate (from 123456, keep 123, from 1234567, either 123 or 1234). In java, you could use byte operations to keep the first half of a number/string/whatever is kept in memory. Thus you will need no iteration, just a byte operation with constant complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For *n* ≥ 4, sqrt(*n*) = 2 sqrt(*n* / 4). For *n* < 1, sqrt(*n*) = 1/2 sqrt(*n* × 4). So you can always multiply or divide by 4 to normalize *n* on the range [1, 4).

Once you do that, take sqrt(4) = 2 as the starting point for Heron's algorithm, since that is the geometric mean and will yield the greatest possible improvement per iteration, and unroll the loop to perform the needed number of iterations for the desired accuracy.

Finally, multiply or divide by all the factors of 2 that you removed at the beginning. Note that multiplying and dividing by 2 or 4 is easy and fast for binary computers.

I discuss this algorithm at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2012/06/01/square-roots/).