# Fast inverse arbitrary power root algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, optimization, square-root

Many sources indicate that well-known [fast inverse square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root) algorithm can be generalized to calculation arbitrary power inverse root. Unfortunately I have not found such C++ implementation and I'm not so good at math to generalize this method by myself. Could you help me to do this or perhaps provide a ready-made solution? I think this will be useful to many, especially with good explanations.

This is the original algorithm and I do not quite understand what I need to change to get for example `1 /cbrt(x)`:

```
float Q_rsqrt( float number )
{
    long i;
    float x2, y;
    const float threehalfs = 1.5F;

    x2 = number * 0.5F;
    y  = number;
    i  = * ( long * ) &y;                       // evil floating point bit level hacking
    i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );               // what the...? 
    y  = * ( float * ) &i;
    y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 1st iteration
//  y  = y * ( threehalfs - ( x2 * y * y ) );   // 2nd iteration, this can be removed

    return y;
}
```

Comment: You need to change the calculation of the initial approximation (magic constant) and construct the corresponding to power newton steps.

Comment: For some values of `n` (including reciprocal cube root) I gave optimal low-accuracy starting approximations in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042673/optimized-low-accuracy-approximation-to-rootnx-n).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm consists of two steps - a rough solution estimation and the solution improvement using several [Newton method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) steps.

## Rough estimation

The basic idea is to use relationship between float number logarithm `log2(x)` and its integer representation `Ix`:

[image]

[image]

(Image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root)

Now use the well-known logarithm [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Product,_quotient,_power,_and_root) for root:

[image].

Combining the identities obtained earlier, we get:

[image]

[image]

Substituting numerical values `L * (B - s) = 0x3F7A3BEA`, so

`Iy = 0x3F7A3BEA / c * (c + 1) - Ix / c;`.

For a simple float point number representation as an integer and back it is convenient to use `union` type:

```
   union 
   { 
      float f; // float representation
      uint32_t i; // integer representation
   } t;

   t.f = x;
   t.i = 0x3F7A3BEA / n * (n + 1) - t.i / n; // Work with integer representation
   float y = t.f; // back to float representation
```

Note that for `n=2` the expression is simplified to `t.i = 0x5f3759df - t.i / 2;` which is identical to original `i  = 0x5f3759df - ( i >> 1 );`

## Newton's solution improvement

Transform equality

[image]

into an equation that should be solved:

[image]

Now construct Newton steps:

[image]

[image]

Programmatically it looks like: `y = y * (1 + n - x * pow(y,n)) / n;`. As an initial `y`, we use the value obtained at **Rough estimation** step.

Note for the particular case of square root (`n = 2`) we get `y = y * (3 - x*y*y) / 2;` which is identically to the original formula `y = y * (threehalfs - (x2 * y * y))`;

Final code as template function. Parameter `N` determines root power.

```
template<unsigned N>
float power(float x) {
   if (N % 2 == 0) return power<N / 2>(x * x);
   else if (N % 3 == 0) return power<N / 3>(x * x * x);
   return power<N - 1>(x) * x;
};

template<>
float power<0>(float x){ return 1; }

// fast_inv_nth_root<2>(x) - inverse square root 1/sqrt(x)
// fast_inv_nth_root<3>(x) - inverse cube root 1/cbrt(x)

template <unsigned n>
float fast_inv_nth_root(float x)
{
   union { float f; uint32_t i; } t = { x };

   // Approximate solution
   t.i = 0x3F7A3BEA / n * (n + 1) - t.i / n;
   float y = t.f;

   // Newton's steps. Copy for more accuracy.
   y = y * (n + 1 - x * power<n>(y)) / n;
   y = y * (n + 1 - x * power<n>(y)) / n;
   return y;
}
```

## Testing

Testing code:

```
int main()
{
   std::cout << "|x          ""|fast2      "" actual2    "
      "|fast3      "" actual3    "
      "|fast4      "" actual4    "
      "|fast5      "" actual5    ""|" << std::endl;

   for (float i = 0.00001; i < 10000; i *= 10)
      std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << std::fixed
      << std::scientific << '|'
      << i << '|'
      << fast_inv_nth_root<2>(i) << " " << 1 / sqrt(i) << "|"
      << fast_inv_nth_root<3>(i) << " " << 1 / cbrt(i) << "|"
      << fast_inv_nth_root<4>(i) << " " << pow(i, -0.25) << "|"
      << fast_inv_nth_root<5>(i) << " " << pow(i, -0.2) << "|"
      << std::endl;
}
```

Results:

```
|x          |fast2       actual2    |fast3       actual3    |fast4       actual4    |fast5       actual5    |
|1.00000e-05|3.16226e+02 3.16228e+02|4.64152e+01 4.64159e+01|1.77828e+01 1.77828e+01|9.99985e+00 1.00000e+01|
|1.00000e-04|9.99996e+01 1.00000e+02|2.15441e+01 2.15443e+01|9.99991e+00 1.00000e+01|6.30949e+00 6.30957e+00|
|1.00000e-03|3.16227e+01 3.16228e+01|1.00000e+01 1.00000e+01|5.62339e+00 5.62341e+00|3.98103e+00 3.98107e+00|
|1.00000e-02|9.99995e+00 1.00000e+01|4.64159e+00 4.64159e+00|3.16225e+00 3.16228e+00|2.51185e+00 2.51189e+00|
|1.00000e-01|3.16227e+00 3.16228e+00|2.15443e+00 2.15443e+00|1.77828e+00 1.77828e+00|1.58487e+00 1.58489e+00|
|1.00000e+00|9.99996e-01 1.00000e+00|9.99994e-01 1.00000e+00|9.99991e-01 1.00000e+00|9.99987e-01 1.00000e+00|
|1.00000e+01|3.16226e-01 3.16228e-01|4.64159e-01 4.64159e-01|5.62341e-01 5.62341e-01|6.30948e-01 6.30957e-01|
|1.00000e+02|9.99997e-02 1.00000e-01|2.15443e-01 2.15443e-01|3.16223e-01 3.16228e-01|3.98102e-01 3.98107e-01|
|1.00000e+03|3.16226e-02 3.16228e-02|1.00000e-01 1.00000e-01|1.77827e-01 1.77828e-01|2.51185e-01 2.51189e-01|
|1.00000e+04|9.99996e-03 1.00000e-02|4.64155e-02 4.64159e-02|9.99995e-02 1.00000e-01|1.58487e-01 1.58489e-01|
```

Comment: Help guys! How to insert LateX formulas on SO?

Comment: I don't think you can insert Latex on SO. Maybe screenshot, crop your math formula and upload it as an image. Or use Google Chart API as directed in this thread: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post

Comment: @DmytroDadyka you can't. mathexchange, stats etc supports MathJax, but not stackoverflow - they think it is too much of a burden for rarely used feature

Comment: Why is inverse power essential? Couldn't we use the same for integer powers?