# Goldschmidt division initialization using CKKS

Tags: python, math, division, seal

I recently found out that I don't really understand how to make the initialization for goldschmidt division denoted in the following article: https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/914.pdf
It isn't really explained how to find the initial value it is just stated that we want the following relation to be upheld: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14E0p.png)

I have the following python code:

```
def gold_div(a,b):
    r = 1/b     
    for i in range(0,10):
        a = r*a
        b = r*b
        r = 2 + -1*b
    return a
```

which works but dividing in a function which is is supposed to be the division algorithm doesn't make much sense.
I was thinking of using his source which he references (http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/Reports/TR-08-2004/rnc6_12_markstein.pdf ) but I get confused about what they are doing.

The picture below illustrates what they are doing: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z50i2.png)

I understand that sgn is a function which basically just finds out if b is negative or positive but I don't really see how I can use their Y0 since it seems to substitute the unknown Y0 with the unknown n (thereby we have 2 unknowns). They also seem to just jump quickly over it since we normally just use a lookup table which I again don't believe we can use since we are using CKKS.

The only thing I can see which might would work is by using the fact that since we are dividing then we can assume that b isn't 0 and thereby we can rewrite the initial expression for y0 to 3/4*b_0<=Y_0<3/2*b_0.

Comment: When computing a starting approximation Y_0 for division based on Newton-Raphson or Goldschmidt iteration, one does in fact typically compute this with the help of a lookup table (or a hardware instruction for an approximate reciprocal that uses a lookup table internally) optionally coupled with interpolating computation. Why is that not possible here? Very low accuracy initial approximation can be created by direct bit manipulation, e.g. as shown in [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32042673/optimized-low-accuracy-approximation-to-rootnx-n).

Comment: As I understand it then bit manipulation is not directly supported by CKKS, as for the lookup table then I am unsure if it would be too much work to implement given it also has to be homomorphic-friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer I can solve the problem by using Newton-rahpson the following way:

```
import numpy as np
def newton_method(a, number_iters = 70):
number = np.finfo(float).eps # number to get inverse of
for i in range(number_iters): # iteration number
    number = number*(2-a*number) # update
return number
```

It uses epsilon because it helps using a very small number so it won't go towards infinity.